# Getting thumbnail for a file with Office Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

When requesting a thumbnail for a file  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/[ID]/thumbnails`, the JSON response still includes a reference to the XXX-my.SharePoint endpoint, and not the Microsoft Graph endpoint. So when I try to download the stream from the URL, I get error 401 (Unauthorized). It seems the token I got for Microsoft Graph is not valid in this context.

Did I miss something here?

Thanks

```
"value": [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "large": {
      "height": 500,
      "url": "https://XXXX-my.sharepoint.com/personal/admin_www_demozone9_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01M6EH6INDNIDWXXE3JVGYE3U6WCSVDMTQ/thumbnails/0/large/thumbnailContent",
      "width": 750
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In the response you get an url to an image hosted in Sharepoint.
To not have a 401 using Sharepoint link, you must pass a token with an audience set to your sharepoint url :

Authorization : Bearer ...

Be careful, the token passed to sharepoint is different than the token passed to the graph api.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but  with the Office Graph API what I expect it's to have the same Bearer token as is mentioned in the documentation. So in this case I could not agree with you
"APIs from Microsoft cloud services through a single REST API endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com). Using the Microsoft Graph, you can turn formerly difficult or complex queries into simple navigations.

The Microsoft Graph gives you:
•A unified API endpoint for accessing aggregated data from multiple Microsoft cloud services in a single response 
•Seamless navigation between entities and and the relationships among them 
•Access to intelligence and insights coming from the Microsoft cloud

**And all this using a single authentication token**."

Comment: Totally agree.  I have filed a bug on this, and we'll be looking in to this issue.  I'll report back once I have more details (if I remember ;)).  Thanks for reporting this.